# Pine Script encryption possible?

Tags: pine-script

Does anyone know a way to encrypt pine script code?
I'd like to share it with someone being able to copy it.

I think there's a way to keep it private, but is there a way to distribute it without it being copied?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There used to be an obfuscation/encryption tool for it in pine v2 times, on one of the few sites that offered tutorials.
It encrypted all variable names, and added a timer in it to break the code.
ah found it : https://www.pinescripts.org/en/cat/tools/

theres a post on their FB that still displays it
https://www.facebook.com/pinescripts/

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is for someone to be able to add your script to a chart while keeping the code hidden then you should post the script with the **invite only** visibility. Note that this feature is for premium users only.